# closures in creating classes not working

Tags: javascript

I have seen the following in all plugins, however when I type this and try to instantiate an object it throws an error saying that it can find the variable 'SomeClass'. Can somebody explain me what this is and why when I try it it does not work.

```
(function(){
    var SomeClass = function(){
        function SomeClass(){

        }
    };
}).call(this);
```

Comment: What is the expected result? How you are going to use this?

Comment: You're defining two local variables. Where would you expect `SomeClass` to be defined?

Comment: take a look at Dropzone.js this is what you will find! I am trying to get to how to handle multiple instances!

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic about this construct.

The top level function runs in the `this` context which could be anything.

Inside it the `SomeClass` variable is created which points to a function which does nothing.

Comment: I've seen that this is used when creating classes. I was wondering how multiple instances are handled. If I understand right, the top level function is a scope for Objects of type SomeClass. But how do you manage click on multiple instances.

Comment: This is a model which can be used for anything. It depends on what you include inside it and what you return.